# Google Charts as Image

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google charts to embed images of charts in the emails. So Each user will have a unique graph.

Can we use the API and embed a unique URL that will render the Charts and deliver an Image to the email Client.

Comment: the image charts feature from google charts works a treat, see http://datamakessense.com/kpi-emails-with-google-charts-url-parameters

Comment: Google Image Charts is now deprecated, see alternatives below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to generate a url that will render an image of a chart using the [Google Chart Wizard](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard). However, that service recently (April I believe) because deprecated. It still works fine, but for a long term solution, you may have to come up with another method.

**Edit**

Another method would be to generate the image and save it to your server before sending the email. You can do this by having a page on your server dedicated to generating the chart by parsing a given slug, and when the chart is loaded send a POST request with the image data. You can access the data URI by using a hidden canvas (HTML5 is required) and the [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) javascript plugin:

```
chart_area = document.getElementById("chart_div").getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementById("chartArea");
svg = chart_area.innerHTML;
canvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas");
canvas.setAttribute('width', chart_area.offsetWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', chart_area.offsetHeight);

canvg(canvas, svg);
image_data_uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get a PNG version of your chart using `chart.getImageURI()` like following:

Needs to be after the chart is drawn, so in the `ready` event!

```
var my_div = document.getElementById('my_div');
var my_chart = new google.visualization.ChartType(chart_div);

google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
  my_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
});

my_chart.draw(data);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue not so long ago and found out your question on SA. ince Google Image Charts is deprecated since 2012, I built **https://image-charts.com** to be a replacement of Google Image Charts in order to embed charts and graphs into emails (right click on the images bellow and checkout the URL):

[image]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=700x300&chxt=x,y&chl=2018|2017|2015&chd=t:60,40,20&cht=pa&chdl=Image|Charts|Rocks&chf=ps0-0,lg,45,ffeb3b,0.2,f443367C,1|ps0-1,lg,45,8bc34a,0.2,0096887C,1|ps0-2,lg,45,EA469E,0.2,03A9F47C,1&chan
```

[image]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=700x300&chd=t:10,25,30,40,12,48,100,20,47,29,84,30,27,50,70&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Jan|1:||50|100&chm=B,FCECF4,0,0,0&chco=E4061C&chdl=Coffee consumed&chma=0,0,20,10&chl=||||||such a very   big project!
```

[image]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=700x300&cht=gv&chl=digraph {a -> b[label="0.2",weight="0.2"];a -> c[label="0.4",weight="0.4"];c -> b[label="0.6",weight="0.6"];c -> e[label="0.6",weight="0.6"];e -> e[label="0.1",weight="0.1"];e -> b[label="0.7",weight="0.7"];}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but we just built https://ChartURL.com for this exact need because despite this question being almost 3.5 years old, the best solution out there until ChartURL was the deprecated Google Image Charts API :)

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

To render Google Charts as an image, you can use [Google Charts Node](https://quickchart.io/documentation/google-charts-image-server/), an open-source project that uses Puppeteer to render the charts.

[google-charts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-charts-node) is available as an NPM library and can be used like so:

```js
const GoogleChartsNode = require('google-charts-node');

function drawChart() {
  const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population',],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000]
  ]);

  const options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  const chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Render the chart to image
const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart);
```

Now you can save the `image` buffer as a file or return it as an HTTP response, etc.  It looks like this:

[image: Google Charts as image]

The Google Charts node renderer is also available as a web service, as described [here](https://quickchart.io/documentation/google-charts-image-server/), so you can use it in any language besides JS.

If you're interested in using a more universal open-source chart format, you can also use [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/), a Chart.js render API.