# JavaScript library to support interactive charts, graphs etc on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I'm looking for a useful library which would help me in drawing different interactive charts, graphs etc on canvas. Basically i'm designing a web paint like application and adding the functionality of these interactive charts etc. so what i want is, when user clicks the specific chart, he can then click anywhere inside the canvas and the chart appears there with the data given by user in a file(i will handle that once i know the data format and stuff). I tried a few libraries but either they don't support drawing inside canvas or they aren't offering any interactivity... what do you guys suggest me to go for?

Comment: you can use https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: yea i was looking into that.. but will it support drawing on canvas? in the examples, it is displaying inside div element. i want something like Chart(context) = new pieChart  (using context of the canvas)

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296804/google-charts-as-image It is a good example for google chart and canvas.

Comment: that is not what i'm looking for actually..

Answer (score 1):

As @Pereira said both chartjs and google chart are good solutions. I will also recommend you take a look at:

- HighchartsJS (http://www.highcharts.com/)
- PolychartJS (http://www.polychartjs.com/)

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have someones:

http://www.chartjs.org/

https://developers.google.com/chart/

I think both are good solutions to you.

Comment: Also see [other threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502827/real-time-data-graphing-on-a-line-chart-with-html5)

Comment: chartjs DOES NOT support 'interactive charts'... and, will google charts support drawing inside a canvas? using the context...

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a project where we did this using the chart.js library. Clicking bars generates a new, more specific graph based on the clicked bar. I think a big part of what made this possible for us was the use of a RESTful API to manage the data. [Check it out](http://www.brysbroughton.com/blog/reggraph-interactive-canvas-chart-with-real-time-updates/) if you're interested.